# ListView not scrolling smoothly even with ViewHolder

Tags: android, performance, listview

I'm making a music player app for Android that uses ViewPager with 4 fragments. One of the fragments has a list of all the songs in the device. The problem is that scrolling through the list is a painful experience. It is not smooth at all. Very stuttery, I should say.

To counter this problem, I implemented the ViewHolder pattern. However, the scrolling experience has not changed one bit.

Please look through my code to see if there is anything wrong with my ViewHolder pattern or if there is any inefficient blocks of code.

Here's the AllSongsFragment.java. I've removed the imports.

```
[Imports Here]

public class AllSongsFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<Song> songArray;
    private ListView songListView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    } // onCreate()
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        songListView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.all_songs_list);
        songArray = new ArrayList<Song>();
        getSongList();
        // Sort the songs
        Collections.sort(songArray, new Comparator<Song>() {
            public int compare(Song a, Song b) {
                // For case-insensitive sorting
                String a1 = a.getTitle().toString().toLowerCase();
                String b1 = b.getTitle().toString().toLowerCase();
                return a1.compareTo(b1);
            }
        });
        AllSongsAdapter songAdt = new AllSongsAdapter(getActivity(), songArray);
        songListView.setAdapter(songAdt);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_songs_fragment_layout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    } //onCreateView()
    public void getSongList() {
    //retrieve song info
        ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
        // Iterate over the List
        if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            //add songs to list
            do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                songArray.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
            }  while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } //getSongList()
} //AllSongsFragment
```

And I have a Song.java file to represent each song.

```
public class Song {
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    //Constructor
    public Song(long songID, String songTitle, String songArtist) {
        id=songID;
        title=songTitle;
        artist=songArtist;
    }
    // get methods
    public long getID() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }
} //.Song
```

And here is the adapter - AllSongsAdapter.java

```
public class AllSongsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Song> songs;
    private LayoutInflater songInf;
    // constructor
    public AllSongsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
        songs = theSongs;
        songInf = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView artist;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songs.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Avoid unneccessary calls to findViewById() on each row, which is expensive!
        ViewHolder vh;
        /* If convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, no inflation required!    * We only inflate a new View when the convertView is null. */
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = songInf.inflate(R.layout.song_item_layout, null);
            // Create a ViewHolder and store references to the children views
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            //map to song layout
            //get title and artist views
            vh.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
            vh.artist = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
        } else {
        // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextViews
            vh = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        //get song using position
        Song currSong = songs.get(position);
        String theTitle = currSong.getTitle();
        String theArtist = currSong.getArtist();
        // Bind that data efficiently!
        vh.title.setText(theTitle);
        if(theArtist.equals("<unknown>") || theArtist.equals("Unknown")) {
            vh.artist.setText("Unknown Artist");
        } else {
            vh.artist.setText(theArtist);
        }
        return convertView;
    } //getView()
}
```

I feel that accessing the get methods of the Song class might have some effect but I'm not sure. What are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason for this.

The layout for each song item is here.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_item_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_item_padding"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#43174c"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_item_title"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_artist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5a1f66"
        android:textSize="@dimen/list_item_second_line"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note the android:ellipsize="marquee" attribute. For every TextView that overflows the display, the end of the line is blurred. I enabled "Show GPU Overdraw" in Developer Settings and found that the blurred portion is showing red, which, I think, means an overdraw of 2x or 3x. So I removed that attribute and now, instead of blurred ends, there is an ellipsis […].

Now the scrolling is buttery smooth.

Comment: The XML was being interpreted as XHTML. Indent four spaces (or use the ctrl-k or the `{}` button in editor) to make a code block. Also an empty row is needed between a text block and a code block. Fixed.